# Batch Share as Web Layer in Arcgis Pro 2.3

Tags: arcgis-pro, web-service, arcgis-portal

I have a federated Arcgis Portal 10.6 and I use Arcgis Pro 2.3 for publishing.

**What I'm looking for**

My final aim is to publish all the layers in a given map individually (not as a single Map Service with all layer at the same time). I want to be able to use individually each layer and it's cache.

**What I do now**

When I wish to publish a layer from Arcgis Pro, I go in the map where all my layers are and right click on the layer I wish to publish.

Then I select Sharing | Share as Web Layer :

[image]

I then have the following panel :

[image]

**My Question**

How do I batch this single operation ? I couldn't find a toobox matching this process. I did find a page mentionning [arcpy.sharing](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/sharing/introduction-to-arcpy-sharing.htm) but I would like to avoid coding if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what version this was added.  But as of 2.4 you can Share as Web Map, and under Configuration, use Split to split various layers into their own feature layers.  These will be their own web feature layers (services) and all be added to the web map.

As [commented by @gisnside](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317087/batch-share-as-web-layer-in-arcgis-pro-2-3#comment572864_349865), there are more precise instructions at [Configure a web map](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/sharing/overview/configure-a-web-map.htm) in the ArcGIS Pro Online Help.

[image: split manipulation]

There is also an ArcGIS Idea to [Publish Individual Web Layers to AGOL](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/publish-individual-web-layers-to-agol/idi-p/932367).

Answer (score 2):

There is no UI option to "batch" sharing single layers as their own service.

Unless you're open to writing Python code, you cannot achieve this workflow. There are not any tools you could chain together in ModelBuilder. Only the arcpy commands.

Note, using the Python/arcpy method, you'd need to identify layers in the map, and then either remove all other layers, or add that layer to an empty map. The [FeatureSharingDraft](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/sharing/featuresharingdraft-class.htm) command uses a map, thus will publish all the layers in the map.